# How to make ListView not to Refresh its Item when already is shown

Tags: android, listview

i am trying to show a Preview of my Videos Inside My ListView, i have Done it by simply Using SeekTo() method, but whenever my ListView refreshes by notifying Adapter, This Process Also Refreshes Obviously,

```
        holder.PvideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse((mCursor.getString
        (mCursor.getColumnIndex("isfile")).split("\\@ADAT")[1]))); 

        holder.PvideoView.seekTo(3000);
```

I Need to Know is There a Way that this Does not Refresh it Self While Already if the Process already is done,

Comment: i wonder if i can do it by SetTag() and checking the tag

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it will always refresh itself. What you could do is to store this information of the current state of your preview inside of your data-class which is used for the listview and setting it to the video after reinitializing.

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, parent, false);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourVideoId);
    NotifyVideoUpdate(videoView, values[position]);
    videoView.seekTo(values[position].CurrentTime);
    return rootView;
  }

  public void NotifyVideoUpdate(VideoView view, VideoModel model){
      //no idea how to add a listener to the video preview, but add it here and change
     // the value inside of your model
  }
```

Comment: you mean whenever convertView is null? because getView gets called no matter view is recycled or not , how ever i tried to use the method i said when convertView is null, but still no chance

Comment: This is not about reusing/recylcing your view. You should to that anyway. I just made a simple example of how to seek to the video when the view gets created/recreated.